# Saving imported objects to DynamoDB in a java application

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to save an object into DynamoDB. I know that the easiest way to do this is to annotate the object with @DynamoDBDocument.
However, in my case, the objects I want to save belong to a package that I can't modify.

I am using the java sdk.

```
import not.my.package.Outsider;

@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "DynamoTable")
public class DynamoTable {
    private Outsider outsider;
    //getters...
    //setters...
}
```

Any ideas on how I can save these objects? I do not want to save them as a string as we are using a Dynamo to SQL plugin for our business purposes.
Thanks.

Comment: Show the sample data.

Comment: @notionquest - I have added an example of the code. does that help?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the OP doesn't have any information about partition key and sort key. The below code auto generates the partition key using annotation `@DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey`. You can change it based on your use case.

**Order class - Similar to DynamoTable**

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "Order")
public class Order implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3534650012619938612L;

    private String orderId;

    private String productName;

    private Integer createDate;

    private Outsider outsider;

    @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "orderId")
    @DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey
    public String getOrderId() {
        return orderId;
    }

    public void setOrderId(String orderId) {
        this.orderId = orderId;
    }

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "productName")
    public String getProductName() {
        return productName;
    }

    public void setProductName(String productName) {
        this.productName = productName;
    }

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "createDate")
    public Integer getCreateDate() {
        return createDate;
    }

    public void setCreateDate(Integer createDate) {
        this.createDate = createDate;
    }

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "outsider")
    public Outsider getOutsider() {
        return outsider;
    }

    public void setOutsider(Outsider outsider) {
        this.outsider = outsider;
    }

}
```

**Outsider class:-**

The attributes in outsider class will be saved as Map attribute in DynamoDB table.

```
@DynamoDBDocument
public class Outsider implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4449726365885112352L;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

}
```

**Code to save data:-**

This code should work as long as you have `dynamoDBClient` object. I have used Spring to inject the object to my service class. There are multiple ways.

```
public Boolean createOrderWithOutsider(String productName, Outsider outsider) {

    DynamoDBMapper dynamoDBMapper = new DynamoDBMapper(dynamoDBClient);

    Order order = new Order();
    order.setProductName(productName);
    order.setOutsider(outsider);

    dynamoDBMapper.save(order);

    System.out.println("Order id : " + order.getOrderId());

    return true;

}
```

**Test code:-**

```
@Test
public void createOrderWithOutsider() {

    Outsider outsider = new Outsider();
    outsider.setFirstName("John");
    outsider.setLastName("Micheal");

    Assert.isTrue(tableOperations.createOrderWithOutsider("Pepsi", outsider));
}
```

**Connection sample:-**

```
<bean id="amazonDynamoDB" class="com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient">
    <constructor-arg ref="amazonAWSCredentials" />
    <property name="endpoint" value="${amazon.dynamodb.endpoint}" />
</bean>
```

**Autowired in service class:-**

```
@Autowired
private AmazonDynamoDBClient dynamoDBClient;
```

**Sample data saved in table:-**

[image: Sample item saved in DynamoDB]

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, I cannot modify the Outsider object. In your reply, you added @DynamoDBDocument to the Outsider class - a class which I cannot modify.